# api-platform + swoole = performance improvement?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, swoole

Is there a "bridge" that incorporates well the Swoole (https://www.swoole.co.uk/) in Api-platform (https://api-platform.com/)?

That main point that to me looks interesting is avoiding the startup of the symfony/api-platform framework on each new request... to get better performance when serving REST API web requests.

Would I get a significant performance improvement with Swoole incorporated in a good manner inside the web request engine in Api-platform?

Answer (score 3):

Swoole looks really interesting, but no, there's not a bridge for that in Api Platform. You could request it or either PR it, but either ways is going to take some time.

However, if you are looking similar performance boost (avoiding the bootstrapping of the framework for example) you should take a look at [PHP-PM](https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm). It is built on top of the famous [React PHP](https://reactphp.org/) library. You'll get better performance than the traditional PHP-FPM+Nginx setup in Symfony. I don't think it will be as fast a Swoole (since we are not talking about a PHP C Extension here), but it will be worth it.